# Sorting on server vs Sorting in Android App. Which one is better?

Tags: android, performance

I need to show a list of cards to user in sorted order(with respect to a property). That list comes from server. Should I perform sorting in android app or on server? Which one is better for performance?
Assume the maximum length of list to be in thousands.

Comment: How powerful is your server?  I would suggest that you have a switch so you can swap from one to the other depending on load or the weakness / power in the android app ...

Comment: Depends on what kind of data and how much of it you are expecting.

Comment: I am marking this question to be closed as any answers will be **primarily opinion-based**

Comment: The answer of such kind of question depends on case. If cards come from DB, then doing order in that level would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the details.
How many clients do you have? how often do they ask for those cards?
How many objects are there to sort?

Server is usually faster,
since it sits typically on better hardware.
However, the server handles requests from many clients,
so if a multiple clients are asking for sort on the same time, or the server is doing other heavy duty CPU work, it will slow it down.

So as a general rule, I would prefer to sort on the client.

An opposite decision can be better sometimes, e.g. only x top most results are needed, no need to send 1 Million results to the client , if it only needs to display top 10...

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, but very hard to answer definitely.

There are a number of things to consider, how many cards will appear in an Activity, how much processing power (Ram/CPU) does your server have, which database will you be using, is it configured correctly, are you avoiding unnecessary joins etc?

Personally, I'd choose to sort *AND LIMIT* on the server, this gives the greatest flexibility if you want to change the sorting algorithm without having to re-release code into the marketplaces. I say, limit, because mobile data is very expensive and sending unused data is a waste.

Also, database joins, sorts and manipulations can be expensive transactions - so if possible, use Caching. I recommend MemCache, easy to setup and easy to use in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for each solution.
If you implement sorting on server side, you'll get benefits like:

- Ability to easily swap algorithm according to new requirements. It could be rather critical for some apps;
- Implement sorting algorithms only once on server-side, not for each platform (in case for Android/iOS/WP development).

But as disadvantages you'll get:

- Slowing down the server (again it may be critical, but it also can be solved);
- You should be careful to not violate the integrity and order with manipulations in app.

Also may be not the worst solution is when server returns type of sorting (of course if app may know all possible type) and the client actually do the sort.

Again, it's all up to you and your environment :)